# Sorting NSArray of NSDictionary...not completely working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

So I have NSMutableArray of NSDictionary items. Each NSDictionary item has a key "name" that should be used to sort the array alphabetically. Except its "sorting" partially works. Its not sorting in exact alphabetical order. It's moving some of the dictionary in order, but leaves some out of order.

```
NSMutableArray *section1 = [champs lastObject];
NSArray *oldSection1 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:section1];
[section1 sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDictionary *dictA = (NSDictionary *)obj1;
    NSDictionary *dictB = (NSDictionary *)obj2;

    NSString *champName1 = dictA[@"name"];
    NSString *champName2 = dictB[@"name"];
    return [champName1 compare:champName2];
}];
// Animation
for (NSDictionary *champInfo2 in section1) {
    if ([oldSection1 indexOfObject:champInfo2] != [section1 indexOfObject:champInfo2]) {
        [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[oldSection1 indexOfObject:champInfo2] inSection:1] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[section1 indexOfObject:champInfo2] inSection:1]];
    }
}
```

I even tried this code

```
NSMutableArray *section1 = [champs lastObject];
NSArray *oldSection1 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:section1];
/*[section1 sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDictionary *dictA = (NSDictionary *)obj1;
    NSDictionary *dictB = (NSDictionary *)obj2;

    NSString *champName1 = dictA[@"name"];
    NSString *champName2 = dictB[@"name"];
    return [champName1 compare:champName2];
}];*/
section1 = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:section1] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]].mutableCopy;
// Animation
for (NSDictionary *champInfo2 in section1) {
    if ([oldSection1 indexOfObject:champInfo2] != [section1 indexOfObject:champInfo2]) {
        [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[oldSection1 indexOfObject:champInfo2] inSection:1] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[section1 indexOfObject:champInfo2] inSection:1]];
    }
}
```

Ok so the problem was I wasn't updating my snapshot of the content before reorganization as I updated it visually. Updated code:

```
// Animation
                for (NSDictionary *champInfo2 in section) {
                    if ([oldSection indexOfObject:champInfo2] != [section indexOfObject:champInfo2]) {
                        [self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[oldSection indexOfObject:champInfo2] inSection:[champs indexOfObject:section]] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:[section indexOfObject:champInfo2] inSection:[champs indexOfObject:section]]];
                        [oldSection removeObject:champInfo2];
                        [oldSection insertObject:champInfo2 atIndex:[section indexOfObject:champInfo2]];
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper part of your code (i.e. the sorting) works fine. It can be simplified if you use sort descriptors, but it's definitely not the issue.

The real problem is with the code that moves things around.

Before the first move the indexing of the `oldSection1` and `self.collectionView` is in sync, i.e. if an item `XYZ` is at index `i` in `oldSection1`, then it is also at index `i` in `self.collectionView`.

After the first move, however, the indexing gets out of sync, because the move is executed only in `self.collectionView`, but not in `oldSection1`. For example, if you start with

```
oldSection1    = C D A B
collectionView = C D A B
```

and you want it to be

```
sorted =         A B C D
```

after the first move of `C` the data is going to look like

```
oldSection1    = C D A B
collectionView = A C D B
```

When it's time to move `D` to its new spot, `C` gets moved instead.

To fix this issue, make `oldSection1` mutable, and execute "parallel" moves as you move things around in `self.collectionView`.

Comment: Understood. So now I move the the item in the collection view and then move it in the old snapshot of the content before move the next item.

Comment: If your array is large (much larger than the view), you might calculate the range of items displayed, and check how many of those will still be displayed after the sorting. If most or many are not visible, for example because you changed the sort order (say people sorted by birthday instead of last name), you might just reload the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks like* your actual **data** is correct, but your **collection view** is displaying them incorrectly since you're iterating over the data, moving one row at a time. This most likely results in re-ordering rows that have already been re-ordered.

Calling `[self.collectionView reloadData]` instead of manually moving rows should resolve this issue.

Comment: I'm trying to use moveItemAtIndexPath: in order to provide a nice animation instead of "poof" it appears.

Comment: @TechGenius Alright. Does this at least display the correct data, though?

Answer (score 0):

To perform multiple UICollectionView item updates (insert/delete/move), it is recommended to use `performBatchUpdates:completion:`.  Otherwise you may encounter invalid indexes.

[Link to official Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/performBatchUpdates:completion:)